# How to Text To Speech a IA text generation that is streaming response

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, text-to-speech

I'm trying to make a TTS on a open source LLM with local API that is streaming me the response to my questions but it's very hard to do it and I find nothing on that subject.

Here's the code:

```
import threading
from queue import Queue
from openai import OpenAI
import time

tts_engine = pyttsx3.init()

client = OpenAI(base_url="http://localhost:1234/v1", api_key="not-needed")

history = [
    {"role": "system", "content": "Vous êtes un assistant intelligent appelé Bob. Vous fournissez toujours des réponses rapides et précises, à la fois justes et utiles et toujours en langue française."},
    {"role": "user", "content": "Bonjour, présentez-vous à quelqu'un qui ouvre ce programme pour la première fois. Soyez concis."},
]

while True:
    user_input = input("> ")
    history.append({"role": "user", "content": user_input})

    start_time = time.time()  # Temps de début de la requête à l'API

    completion = client.chat.completions.create(
        model="local-model",
        messages=history,
        temperature=0.8,
        stream=True,
    )

    new_message = {"role": "assistant", "content": ""}
    
    for chunk in completion:
        if chunk.choices[0].delta.content:
            generated_text = chunk.choices[0].delta.content
            print(generated_text, end="", flush=True)
            new_message["content"] += generated_text

    history.append(new_message)

    end_time = time.time()
    response_time = end_time - start_time  
    print("\nTemps de réponse de l'API:", response_time, "secondes")
```

So I tried multiple thing like a loop that is looking for the new word that is being generating but I think that is not good approach and it doesn't work.

Any suggestions?